# Scala sbt assemblyMergeStrategy issue

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I've been trying for the last two or three days to solve some issue with my sbt assembly build logic. It's related to `assemblyMergeStrategy`. SBT version 1.2.8.

It looks something like this:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
      case PathList("javax", "inject", _ @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
      case PathList("javax", "servlet", _ @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
      case PathList("javax", "activation", _ @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
      case PathList("org", "apache", _ @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
      case PathList("com", "google", _ @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
      case PathList("com", "typesafe", _ @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
      case PathList("com", "microsoft", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
      case "about.html" => MergeStrategy.rename
      case "plugin.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
      case "log4j.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
      case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) =>
        xs match {
          case "MANIFEST.MF" :: Nil => MergeStrategy.discard
          case "mailcap" :: Nil => MergeStrategy.last
          case "mimetypes.default" :: Nil => MergeStrategy.last
          // Concatenate everything in the services directory to keep GeoTools happy.
          case "services" :: _ :: Nil =>
            MergeStrategy.concat
          // Concatenate these to keep JAI happy.
          case "javax.media.jai.registryFile.jai" :: Nil | "registryFile.jai" :: Nil |
              "registryFile.jaiext" :: Nil =>
            MergeStrategy.concat
          case name :: Nil => {
            // Must exclude META-INF/*.([RD]SA|SF) to avoid "Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes" exception.
            if (name.endsWith(".RSA") || name.endsWith(".DSA") || name.endsWith(".SF"))
              MergeStrategy.discard
            else
              MergeStrategy.first
          }
          case _ => MergeStrategy.first
        }
      case x =>
        val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
        oldStrategy(x)
        //MergeStrategy.first
    }
```

For some reason, I don't think the com.microsoft merge strategy is being selected or something like that.

```
[error] 1 error was encountered during merge
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/t23528/.ivy2/cache/com.microsoft.azure/azure-mgmt-appservice/jars/azure-mgmt-appservice-1.23.0.jar:maven.properties
[error] /Users/t23528/.ivy2/cache/com.microsoft.azure/azure-mgmt-batch/jars/azure-mgmt-batch-1.23.0.jar:maven.properties
[error] /Users/t23528/.ivy2/cache/com.microsoft.azure/azure-mgmt-batchai/jars/azure-mgmt-batchai-1.23.0.jar:maven.properties
```

And many more from the Microsoft jars, all with the same `maven.properties` error.

If I leave the last part of the assembly as

```
case x =>
  //val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
  //oldStrategy(x)
  MergeStrategy.first
```

the build passes. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried upgrading to the latest sbt version 1.3.13 and it looks like it's using some other cache, no longer `ivy2` but `Coursier`.

```
[error] 1 error was encountered during merge
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/t23528/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-appservice/1.23.0/azure-mgmt-appservice-1.23.0.jar:maven.properties
[error] /Users/t23528/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-batch/1.23.0/azure-mgmt-batch-1.23.0.jar:maven.properties
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this:

```scala
case x if x.contains("com.microsoft") => MergeStrategy.last
```

Comment: I tried it just now. Same error as before. It feels like something very strange is going on.